# Scatterplot legend - colorbars in a loop?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, scatter-plot

Currently I have a code setting like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.close('all')

nSub = 17
nMonths = 12
nYears=16

datalist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q']

DATA   = np.random.rand(nSub,nMonths,nYears)
DATA1  = np.random.rand(nSub,nMonths,nYears)

DIFF = DATA  - DATA1

fig, ax = plt.subplots (nrows=1, ncols=1)

for imonth in range(12):
    x = imonth + 1
    x_sub = np.linspace(x-0.5, x+0.5, nSub) 

    for isub in range(len(datalist)):
        x_plot = np.ones((nYears,), dtype=np.float32)*x_sub[isub]
        y_plot = DIFF[isub, imonth, :]
        ax.scatter(x_plot, y_plot, label=datalist[isub]) 
        ax.set_xticks(np.arange(1.0, 12.+1, 1.0))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The figure of which looks something like this:
[image: scatter_test]

The x-axis represents months (nMonths), the scatterplot is the repetition of 17 different datasets (nSub) every month over 16 years (nYears).

The problem I have is that I don't know how to correctly assign the scatterplot colors that would color only each of the dataset from the datalist (isub) with the same color every month (for all nYears the same for every imonth).

That means, that every 'a' would be of the same color every month. At the end I should have only 17 (nSub) colors and the same number of elements in my legend.

How do I solve this?

Comment: is using `seaborn` an option?

Comment: no, unfortunately I don't have access to it where I run the code :/

Comment: Not sure if seaborn is of any help here (at least not until they release their new scattery function). But I also have a problem understanding what you want to show in this graph. This is mainly because you seem to manipulate the data within the loop you use for plotting. It would be better to first generate the data in completeness and then try to plot that data.